# How can I align these product cards to grid?

Tags: html, css

I need to adjust these items to a grid, the first three are aligned but the following are all throughout the webpage [the first three are perfectly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4oz7.png)
I would like to align the rest of the cards like the first three. If someone can help me I would be really grateful.
Thanks. Here is the code below.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
    <h2>Ултразвучни системи:</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\herai10.jpg"alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HERA I10</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\heraw10.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HERA W10</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100" >
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\rs85.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">RS85</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Радиологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch ">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\WS80A.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">WS80A with Elite</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\rs80a.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">RS80A with Prestige</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Радиологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs70a.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS70A with Prime</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно, Радиологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs60.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS60</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs50.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS50</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs40.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS40</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs30.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS30</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hm70a.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HM70A with Plus</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно, Точка на Грижење.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\h60.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">H60</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\sonoacer7.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Sonoace R7</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /.row -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a extra closing `</div>` tag that is causing the alignment to break.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
    <h2>Ултразвучни системи:</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\herai10.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HERA I10</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\heraw10.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HERA W10</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\rs85.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">RS85</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Радиологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch ">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\WS80A.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">WS80A with Elite</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\rs80a.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">RS80A with Prestige</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Радиологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs70a.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS70A with Prime</h4>
        <p class="card-text">
          Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно, Радиологија.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs60.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS60</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs50.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS50</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs40.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS40</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hs30.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HS30</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hm70a.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">HM70A with Plus</h4>
        <p class="card-text">
          Акушерство, Гинекологија, Кардиоваскуларно, Точка на Грижење.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\h60.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">H60</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\sonoacer7.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Sonoace R7</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Акушерство, Гинекологија.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Спецификации</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped never saw that extra </div> thank you for answering my question and helping out!! Now it's all aligned properly.